# Is it still possible to do double Nexus explosion on surrender in LoL?

Tags: league-of-legends

Before update of Victory/Defeat animations, it was possible to trigger Nexus explosion animation twice - because of dropping it's health and because of surrender vote done in a small time window.

Is it still possible after this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's still possible.

You have to be way more precise with your timing, but it's happened to me since the update to SR.

Comment: Does this mean that both teams get a win?

Comment: @VedaadShakib No both teams don't get a win. The team whose Nexus explodes last will lose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. You must agree to surrender before the enemy team kills your Nexus though. It happened to me earlier today in fact.